# Android view alert msg when i receive messege from service

Tags: android, uialertview, android-alertdialog

Hi i have a problem on my project, i have one activity and service , i use messenger to communication with us. I would view a alert dialog when i receive a message from service ,but this dialog is not appear. On log cat i see a log with text.
Do you have a solution .
My code is:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import ztl.Bologna.activity.Database.DBopenHelper;
import ztl.Bologna.OverlayList;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity{
    private MyLocationOverlay mOverlay;

    protected static MapView gmap;
    private DBopenHelper db;
    OverlayList overlay;
    private GuiHandler guiHandler;
    private Messenger messenger;
    public double destLat = 44.497592;
    public double destLong = 11.356151;
    private double Long = 11.352693;
    private double Lat = 44.497271;
    Intent serviceIntent;
    public Cursor cursor;
    int version ;

    //final MapController control = gmap.getController();
    GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(Lat * 1e6),(int)(Long * 1e6));

    //Context c = getApplicationContext();


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        Context context;
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Log.e("context",""+context);
        //db = new DBopenHelper(context);
        db = new DBopenHelper(this,1);
        guiHandler = new GuiHandler(this);
        Log.d("put", "database");
        gmap=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        gmap.setClickable(true);
        gmap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mOverlay=new MyLocationOverlay(this,gmap);

        //control.setCenter(gp);

        // control.animateTo(gp);
        gmap.getOverlays().add(mOverlay);
        Lat=44.497271;
        Long=11.352693;
        updateMapOverlay();
        db.close();

        messenger = new Messenger(guiHandler);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,MessaggeService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(MessaggeService.CALLER, MessaggeService.POSITION);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(MessaggeService.MESSENGER, messenger);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.e("Debug", "Service Started from activity");
        //ms = new MessaggeService(overlay,gmap,c);

        ///destLat = mOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
        //destLong = mOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();


    }


    private void addOpenPoint(GeoPoint g) {
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(g, "", "");
        overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        Log.e("over",""+overlayitem);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

            //  @Override
            public void run() {
                //gmap.invalidate();
                gmap.getController().animateTo(mOverlay.getMyLocation());
                gmap.getController().setZoom(16);



                //updateMapOverlay();

            }

        });     
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_maps, menu);
        return true;
    }


    void updateMapOverlay() {
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = gmap.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //mapOverlays.clear();
        overlay = new OverlayList(drawable, this); 
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        Cursor cursor = db.getZtlStreet();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Integer lat = (int) (cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude")) * 1e6);
                Integer lon = (int) (cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude")) * 1e6);

                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
                addOpenPoint(p);
            }
        }



    }
    public static class GuiHandler extends Handler {
        // TODO da unificare con quello ChooseEVSEActivity
        public static final int FALSE = 0;
        public static final int TRUE = 1;
        // tiene il conto del tempo che è passato dall'ultima volta;

        WeakReference<MapsActivity> wrActivity;

        public GuiHandler(MapsActivity activity) {
            wrActivity = new WeakReference<MapsActivity>(activity);
        }

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            final MapsActivity activity = wrActivity.get();
            /*Create alert dialog to access on ztl street*/
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage("Accesso Ztl non puoi accedere");
            builder.setPositiveButton("chiudi",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                //@Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            switch (msg.what) {
            case MessaggeService.UPDATE_UI_MSG:
                AlertDialog alertMsg = builder.create();
                alertMsg.show();


                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}



My service with message is :

    for(int i = 0 ; i< overlay.size();i++){

                Log.e("item : ","n"+overlay.size());
                OverlayItem item = overlay.getItem(i);
                Location l1 = new Location("");
                l1.setLatitude(item.getPoint().getLatitudeE6());
                Log.e("l1", "l1"+l1.getLatitude());
                l1.setLongitude(item.getPoint().getLongitudeE6());
                Location l2 = new Location("");
                l2.setLatitude(destLat);
                l2.setLongitude(destLong);
                Log.e("l2", "l2"+l2.getLatitude());



                try {
                    String caller = "generic";
                    try {
                        caller = intent.getStringExtra(CALLER);
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {

                            if (POSITION.equals(caller)) {
                                positionMessenger = (Messenger) extras.get(MESSENGER);
                                Log.e("position",""+positionMessenger);
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Instantiating " + caller + " Messenger OK :" + positionMessenger);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Log.e(UpdaterService.class.getName(), "Error instantiating " + caller + " Messenger" + e.getMessage());
                        //se il servizio non è ancora partito allora esco da esso in modo che venga istanziato correttamente
                        if(!doUpdate) {
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                    }
                    if (l2.distanceTo(l1) >100) {
                        Log.e("distance","Ztl non puoi accedere");


                        Message msg = Message.obtain();
                        Log.e("msg",""+msg);
                        msg.what = UPDATE_UI_MSG;
                        positionMessenger.send(msg);
                        Log.e("send","send");
                    }} catch (RemoteException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the `builder` to show at the end

```
builder.show();
```